# Can Tabs or Spaces break tests or programs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, rspec-rails

I read "Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3" and try to figure out tests. I just realized that my (very simple) tests broke because i was somehow mixing tabs and spaces for indentaion.

As a result I received errors like this:

```
[31mURI::InvalidURIError:←[0m
       ←[31mthe scheme http does not accept registry part: www.example.comstatic_pages (or bad hostname?)←[0m
```

After I copy/pasted the first part of the test (the one passing) and changed the content all the tests passed.

**My question:** Is there a "right" way to do it, or just stick to one method (tabs or spaces)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs/spaces should have *zero* effect on your tests.  There are some languages where it matters, but ruby isn't one of them.  I'd hazard a guess that what may have looked like spaces was in fact some invisible utf8 characters causing the problem.  I've had that happen before when I copy and paste from other sources.  And simply re-writing it based on what I see fixes it.

Bottom line... use whatever you want... be consistent just to make your life simpler, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on the same prob, and I think our problem was forgetting the first slash (/) on the visit statement.
The following code makes the test to output an URI error.

```
visit 'static_pages/about'
page.should have_content('About us')
```

Write down the first slash and the code will work as espected.

```
visit '/static_pages/about'
page.should have_content('About us')
```